# Download old version of Amazon Appstore on android

Tags: stock-android, amazon-appstore

I accidentally updated my amazon appstore to amazon underground without backing it up. It does not work on my device for some reason (I can't download normal apps I can ONLY download underground and paid apps, weird). There's no way to downgrade so I was wondering if someone could give me a direct link/ server directory to the old version before they went underground (e.g. http://s3.amazon.com/link/to/old/appstore.apk )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest and trusted way would be to download it from **[APK MIRROR](http://apkmirror.com)**. 
This is by far the best site for downloading Android apks(apps). You just have to type the name of the app in the search bar and you'll get  search result for the app with different version. You can download the version of the app you like. You should try it. Recommended.

Comment: Thanks but I can't find the old version of the amazon app. Cool site , I might use it ☺

Comment: Were you looking for this?   http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/amazon-mobile-llc/appstore/appstore-release-20-0000-912-1c_650000010-release/amazon-appstore-release-20-0000-912-1c_650000010-android-apk-download/

Comment: Not quite but it'll work. Thanks! What I had before was just called Amazon. But it had an apps and games tab. It was not amazon appstore but it'll work.